# why Win7 User folder can be accessed by another user and also in the network?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, permissions

I just found at home I (an administrator user) can access other users folders under the C:\Users, even one of the folders belongs to another administrator account. I thought the folders under Users belong to specific user should be private. But they are not. Is this right? I am using Windows 7 enterprise and professional edition. Yes, there is a popup window to tell you you don't have permission but it will give you permission if you want.

I also found the Users folder by default is visible and accessible via Network. I don't think this is right.

All above are happened at home and I just setup a home network with an old netgear router.  All machines are my machines bought used with win7 professional and enterprise OSs.

Comment: Admins have access to other admins stuff. This is normal. As for the network side of your question, I'm not certain.

Comment: What you are describing is completely normal.